# AH00534: httpd: Configuration error: No MPM loaded. when copying my own httpd.config

Tags: apache, docker

This thing is really strange...
If I build a docker image using the following docker file I receive the error

```
#TO BE FINISHED

FROM httpd:2.4
COPY / /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/operator

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY ./config/my-httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf


EXPOSE 80
```

For a simple test I've just taken the one from the bulk container of httpd:2.4 and replaced it inside my config/my-httpd.config but still give me an error.

If I comment on the #COPY it works.. but what it's not clear to me is why... it's the same that are contained in the official httpd image

I forgot to say that I'm using Docker for windows Desktop application and I'm in linux mode

What am I doing wrong?

## UPDATE #1

I've understood that the problem is the http.d file size... I try to explain.

Reading the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd), I used `docker run --rm httpd:2.4 cat /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf > my-httpd.conf`
But this generates me on Windows machine a file around 42Kb.

I've mounted a volume and copied the file on a simple running httpd image and it's 20kb. using this one works.... why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on windows when creating the copy with `docker run --rm httpd:2.4 cat /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf > my-httpd.conf`.

I changed the encoding of `my-httpd.conf` to utf-8 and switched from CRLF to LF.

So the problem seems to be, that on windows the file gets saved with different encoding and Carriage Return before Line Feed.